# SAS SQL - how do I remove rows in a table where a column doesn't contain a specific variable?

Tags: variables, uniqueidentifier, proc

| Unique ID | Type | TypeID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Company | 123422 |
| 10002 | Company | 123477 |
| 10002 | Subsidiary | 12000 |
| 10005 | Company | 123455 |
| 10005 | Subsidiary | 12125 |
| 10006 | Subsidiary | 12300 |

So I have a table where a unique ID can have either or one or two rows of data associated with it. I want to extract the rows and delete those unique IDs where it only has one row of information. For example, the top one and the bottom one from my data set above I don't need it. How can I do this in a PROC SQL step?
Many thanks!

I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that in PROC SQL?  Is the data already sorted by the ID variable?

Comment: The data is not sorted and I am a complete novice. The data set is in the millions and I just assumed that PROC SQL would make it quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think why you would use PROC SQL for something like that.  Just use a data step.

```
data want;
   set have;
   by id ;
   if first.id and last.id then delete;
run;
```

If you really had to do it with SQL you could use a HAVING clause.

```
proc sql;
   create table want as
     select *
     from have
     group by id
     having count(*) > 1
   ;
quit;
```

Comment: I think I worked it out: proc transpose data=have out=want (DROP=_name_);
    by uniqueid;
   var type_ID;
   ID type;
run;